# How can I debug this program?

Tags: c, for-loop

I wrote some C code that was supposed to transpose a 3x3 integer matrix using the function "transpose". However, there is something wrong with the code, but I can't figure it out. Can someone help me with identifying the mistake, please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a[3][3];

void main()
{
    int i, j;
    void transpose(int x[3][3]);

    printf("Enter a 3x3 matrix:\n");
    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        ;
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
            ;
        {
            scanf_s("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("The original matrix is:\n");
    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        printf("%d %d %d\n", a[i][0], a[i][1], a[i][2]);
    transpose(a);
    printf("The transposed matrix is:\n");
    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        printf("%d %d %d\n", a[i][0], a[i][1], a[i][2]);
    getchar();
    getchar();
}

void transpose(int x[3][3])
{
    int t;
    t = x[1][0];
    x[1][0] = x[0][1];
    x[0][1] = t;
    t = x[2][0];
    x[2][0] = x[0][2];
    x[0][2] = t;
    t = x[2][1];
    x[2][1] = x[1][2];
    x[1][2] = t;
}
```

Comment: How do you know something is wrong? Do you get a compiler error or a runtime error? What is the error? Also, C/C++ is not a language - C or C++, pick one.

Comment: woe and behold - Simple indentation applied, and a problem stares at us right in the face. Your `for` loops preform no actions

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++);` --- this is an empty loop. It does nothing three times. Try removing the semicolon (this bug appears twice)

Comment: Didn't you get a compiler warning about the semicolons on your `for` loops?

Comment: Enabling high warning levels on your compiler will let you catch these things easily. You *probably* should do so, and if you already have, you might want to start paying attention to the warnings the compiler produces.

Comment: Aside: `for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)` is using a magic number that is *different* from the magic number used to dimension the array. Better would be `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)` and even better would be that `3` specified in *one* place only, either with a `#define` or with a `const int`.

Comment: Sorry the compiler didn't show any warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semi-column (;) after each `for` loop. Those are empty `for` loops in your program. They loop without doing anything.

Comment: This is just one of many problems

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you!